How do I define a custom method for @ operator?
Numpy uses the @ operator for matrix multiplication between two arrays.
I have my own class for which I want to define a method using the @ operator.
How should this be done? I define my own __add__, __sub__, __mul__, etc, but how do I make one for @?
I would prefer not to subclass numpy.ndarray.
I expected there would be a magic method like def __at__(self, other) or something, but no. I am surprised I am having so much trouble finding anything about this. Thanks

The name is __matmul__
